# Mysql dump is not full

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump, phpmyadmin

I have installed fresh ubuntu 16.04 with apache2.4 and php7.0 on it and then installed mariadb. Here is version: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.35-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2.

After this fresh installation I noticed that I can't create normal mysql dump of some bases from any sources including phpmyadmin export, MysqlWorkbench and mysqldump command in shell. The file that is created is very small and most of tables does not contain INSERT query although there are data in tables.

As the result I got 600kb large dump file of 300mb database. I have tried to change max_allowed_packet is set to 2gb so it cannot be the case. As for --no-data argument then it is set to false and event if it would not be - it's very strange that only some tables contain INSERT with data and other are not. User privileges are also fully set for database i'm trying to dump.

I'm trying to fix this for almost 3 days with no result and i would really appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check that you're really using the database user you think you are using. E.g. you're using the `root` user, but maybe there are multiple `root` users, each with a different `host`, and only one of them has grants to see all the data. Try "select current_user();" and "show grants;" in phpmyadmin or MySQL Workbench to be sure.

Comment: Make a list of tables (or databases) with no data.  Figure out what is common to them.

Comment: In users table there is only one root and for current databese I'm using root@localhost user with full privilges.

Comment: As for second question - there is nothink different between tables: they are all have same type and even size.

Comment: @AlexanderZelenchuk Exactly what are the grants for your root user? The devil is in the details.

Comment: @AlexanderZelenchuk Please review this link  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#max_allowed_packet  and observe the max allowed packet size of 1GB.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks, but this is the first thing i have checked. Max allowed packet in my case is set to 2GB.

Comment: @AlexanderZelenchuk Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report, 
E) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop, top & mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused   
for server tuning analysis.